# dataTables sorting not working

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a dataTable where i populating some data but i need the sorting operation enabled on that table.But my sorting is not working.This is my code i have done so far.

```
 $('#example').dataTable( { 
                                "processing": true,
                                "serverSide": true,
                                aaSorting: [[2, 'desc']],
                                "ajax": url,
                                "columns": [
                                    {"data" : "code"},        
                                    { "data": "description"},
                                    { "data" : "mrpString"},
                                    { "data":"unitDescription"},
                                    { "data":"moq"}
                                ],
                                 "columnDefs": [
                                             {
                                                 "targets": [ 0 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": false,
                                                 "sortable" :false

                                             },
                                          {
                                                 "targets": [ 1 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": true,
                                                 "sortable" :true

                                             },
                                          {
                                                 "targets": [ 2 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": false

                                             },
                                          {
                                                 "targets": [ 3 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": true

                                             },
                                          {
                                                 "targets": [ 4 ],
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "visible": true,
                                                 "searchable": true

                                             }
                                         ], 

                                      "aoColumnDefs": [
                                                    { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [0,1,2,3,4] }
                                                  ] ,  
 "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
                                     $("td:eq(0)",row).html("<a href='"+data.url+"' target='_new'>"+data.code+"<//a/> ");
                                     //alert(data.parentCategoryId);
                                        /* $('td:eq(6)', row).html( '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedIds" value="'+data.id+'" />' ).attr("class","checkIds");
                                        $('td:eq(0)',row).attr('id','_'+data.id); */
                                 }

                            });
                    });
```

This is my code i have done searching is also working but i want sorting enanled ,somebody please help

Comment: Would you mind telling us which datatable plug in you are using?
Have you tried using something like `"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]`

Comment: @Serv jquery.dataTables.js i am using

Comment: serverSide:false is solving the purpose but it is disabling the paging

Comment: Also: you did not post the complete js code. There is at least some closing parenthesis missing, if not some other options

Comment: @Serv my sorting issue is done but "serverSide": false, is disabling the paging capacity can you help???

Comment: @Serv complete js code is here now i am facing the paging issue

Comment: @lucifer - Can you tell us what approach are you using for datatable? Client side datatable or server-side datatable? Based on client-side or server-side approach, your php code or dot net or java code means any server-side code depends.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post.. but check it out..

Server side means you are doing everything server side. On the server, whatever method that fetches the data for your table, is also responsible for the paging and sorting of your table. My sorting wasn't working.. then I realized that my server-side method wasn't doing the sorting! So.. in a nutshell, I added this to the server-side method or function responsible for providing data for my table (C#):
(Note: "data" is a list of objects for my data table)

```
var myJsonOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTableOrder>>(Request.Params["JsonOrder"]);
// Sorting
if (myJsonOrder != null && myJsonOrder.Count > 0)
{
    var firstOrder = myJsonOrder.FirstOrDefault();

    switch (firstOrder.column)
    {
        case 1:
            data = firstOrder.dir == "asc" ? data.OrderBy(x => x.TripName).ToList() : data.OrderByDescending(x => x.TripName).ToList();
            break;
        case 2:
            data = firstOrder.dir == "asc" ? data.OrderBy(x => x.TripStartDate).ToList() : data.OrderByDescending(x => x.TripStartDate).ToList();
            break;
        case 3:
            data = firstOrder.dir == "asc" ? data.OrderBy(x => x.NumTravelers).ToList() : data.OrderByDescending(x => x.NumTravelers).ToList();
            break;
        case 4:
            data = firstOrder.dir == "asc" ? data.OrderBy(x => x.NumCardsAssigned).ToList() : data.OrderByDescending(x => x.NumCardsAssigned).ToList();
            break;
    }
}
```

There is other data available in the request, such as the columns and search query:

```
var myJsonColumns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTableColumn>>(Request.Params["JsonColumns"]);
var myJsonOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTableOrder>>(Request.Params["JsonOrder"]);
var myJsonSearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTableSearch>(Request.Params["JsonSearch"]);
```

Edit: Sorry, learning this as I'm going.. that column / order / search data is available on the server because in my AJAX call for dataTables, I am passing the data to the server:

```
inactiveTravelerDataTable = $("#inactive-traveler-list-data-table").dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "jQueryUI": true,
        "searching": false,
        "dom": 'rtipl',
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/Trip/JsonInactiveTravelerList/',
            "data": function(d) {
                d.TripId = $('#TripId').val();
                d.JsonColumns = JSON.stringify(d.columns);
                d.JsonOrder = JSON.stringify(d.order);
                d.JsonSearch = JSON.stringify(d.search);
            },
            "type": "POST"
        }
        //.... Continued on...
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Regards,